# Code won't launch

Tags: java, eclipse

Ok, this code won't launch. It will launch the other class. Yes I did name the The class This, so no error there.

```
package com.thekyle.hi;

class This {
    double b;
    int e;
    double val;

    This(double base, int exp) {
        this.b = base;
        this.e = exp;

        this.val = 1;
        if (exp==0) return;
        for (; exp > 0; exp--)
            this.val = this.val * base;
System.out.println(exp);
    }

    double get_pwr() {
        return this.val;
    }
}
```

So any way to make this launch. Also running configurations doesn't work.

Comment: There is no main method in this class. So cannot be executed.

Comment: There is no Main Method!!!! so why it should launch??

Comment: Learn about java program entry point i.e.main method : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/#MAIN

Comment: there is no main method here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have commented, this code will not run because your `main` method is probably in different `class`. It looks like you are trying to make your `This` class be an object in your  main method. Here are some code examples and explanations of what I changed.

**This.java**

1. All of the `this` keywords you have put in the class are redundant, so I removed them.
2. Your `for loop` is improperly set up. I created it with an index of `i` which is assigned the value of exp.
3. To make a variable equal to itself times something else, you can use `*=`. For example, `a=a*b` is equivalent to `a*=b`.

   ```
   class This
   {
       double b;
       int e;
       double val;

       This(double base, int exp)
       {
           b = base;
           e = exp;
           val = 1;

           if (exp == 0)
           {
               return;
           }
           for (int i = exp; i > 0; i--)
           {
               val*=base;
           }

       }

       double get_pwr()
       {
           return val;
       }
   }
   ```

**MyClass.java**

1. This class contains the `main` method, which is the method that the Java virtual machine looks for to start.
2. I've created an object of your `This` class. You made it's constructor take a `double` base and an `int` exp, so I have given it a double and an int.
3. After creating the object, the calculations are complete. You made a `getter` for the variable `val` which has the result of your computation. Simply call the method and print it out, which is the the `System.out.println()` call does.

   ```
   public class myClass
   {

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
           This myThis = new This(2, 6);
           System.out.println(myThis.get_pwr());
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have main method so your code will not execute. Main method is entry point to your application.so You can write main method in your class as

```
public static void main(String []args)
{
    This obj = new This(2,2);
    System.out.println(get_pwr());
}
```